# Matlab, Python: Fixing colormap to specified values

Tags: python, matlab, masking, color-mapping

It is a simple but common task required when trying to fix a colormap according to a 2D matrix of values.
To demonstrate consider the problem in **Matlab**, the solution does not need to be in **Matlab** (i.e., the code presented here is only for demonstration purpose).

```
x = [0,1,2; 3,4,5; 6,7,8];
imagesc(x)
axis square
axis off
```

So the output is as:
[image]
when some values change to over the maximum value it happens like:

```
x = [0,1,2; 3,4,5; 6,7,18];
```

which looks logical but makes problems when we wish to compare/trace elements in two maps. Since the colormap association is changed it is almost impossible to find an individual cell for comparison/trace etc.
[image]
The solution I implemented is to mask the matrix as:

```
x = [0,1,2; 3,4,5; 6,7,18];
m = 8;
x(x>=m) = m;
```

which works perfectly.
Since the provided code requires searching/filtering (extra time consuming!) I wonder if there is **a general/more efficient way** for this job to be implemented in **Matlab**, **Python** etc?

One of the cases that this issue occurs is when we have many simulations sequentially and wish to make a sense-making animation of the progress; in this case each color should keep its association fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing is pretty quick so I don't think you need worry.

However, in Matlab, you can pass in the `clims` argument to `imagesc`:

```
imagesc(x,[0 8]);
```

This maps all values above 8 to the top colour in the colour scale, and all values below 0 to the bottom colour in the colour scale, and then stretches the scale for colours in-between.

[`imagesc documentation`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html).

Answer (score 3):

In **Python** using package [`MatPlotLib`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) the solution is as follows:

```
import pylab as pl
x = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,18]]
pl.matshow(x, vmin=0, vmax=8)
pl.axis('image')
pl.axis('off')
show()
```

So `vmin` and `vmax` are boundary limits for the full range of colormap.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = figure;
x = [0,1,2; 3,4,5; 6,7,8];
imagesc(x)
axis square
axis off

limits = get(gca(f1),'CLim');

f2 = figure;
z = [0,1,2; 3,4,5; 6,7,18];
imagesc(z)
axis square
axis off
caxis(limits)
```