# Automatically stretch a colormap in python for better visualization

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, color-mapping

I'm using matplotlib to plot things that have a lot of data clustered around values 0, .5, and 1.  So it is difficult to see the difference between values within each cluster with a sequential colormap (which is what I want to use).

I would like to "stretch" the colormap around the values where my data clusters, so that you can see the contrast within each cluster as well as between clusters.

I saw this similar question, but it doesn't quite get me to where I want:
[Matlab, Python: Fixing colormap to specified values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062614/matlab-python-fixing-colormap-to-specified-values)

Thanks!

Comment: So if that question doesn't get you quite where you want, where exactly do you want to get?  What are you asking for?  An idea for a solution?  Code for an idea for a solution?

Comment: You can not have both if you want to use a linear scale.  If you use a non-linear (non-log) scale, then your color map is useless.  Either distort your normalization (so that the values are evenly distributed), use three different color maps, or distort a colormap by hand.

Comment: I was looking for code.  I figure someone else would have had similar problems and might have a nice general purpose solution lying around.

I've thought about it more since then, and I think an idea for a solution would be to simply rescale the data values so they are evenly spaced.  

But I don't need this feature right now.  I switched to mayavi which is working much better in general (I'm doing 3D plots), although I'm having a bit of trouble re-implementing this part of my code, so I haven't gotten to the point where this might be an issue again yet.

Comment: Here is a related question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528097/1558890